# Remove unnecessary parameter from nested resource controller in Laravel 4.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, nested-routes

I am developing an API through Laravel using Resource Controllers which are linked through the `routes.php` file. See the example below:

```
// API routes
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'v1'), function() {

    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
    Route::resource('users.profile', 'UserProfileController');
    Route::resource('users.tasks', 'UserTaskController');

});
```

Generally, Laravel does a good job at handling these routes. But there is one exception that I have where I struggle with. My database model is designed to have a one-to-one relationship between the `users` table and the `user_profiles` table by looking at the foreign key `user_id` in the `user_profiles` table. This means that it is acting on a *identifying relationship*, so it doesn't have an own primary key, it actually borrows the key of the `users` table.

Now, I want to update the `UserProfile` model through the `UserProfileController` that gets called when the following (example) URL is entered: `http://api.projectX.dev:8000/v1/users/{id of the user}/profile`. But Laravel forces me to have a URL like this: `http://api.projectX.dev:8000/v1/users/{id of the user}/profile/{some other useless ID}`.

Is there any way to magically remove that last ID from the resources route and just take advantage of the first ID?

I hope that somebody can help me with this, because finding the answer to this question is actually pretty hard to find right now.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a [nested resource controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) *(scroll down a bit)*. Essentially saying that one resource controller belongs under another resource controller. You can use `php artisan routes` to see exactly what routes are being generated.

Sounds like you'll need to use a combination of resource controllers and explicitly defined routes to get the exact setup you're after. I don't know enough about how you want to control updating/deleting profiles, or I'd offer something more substantial than that.

Comment: I have ran the `php artisan routes` command and got the following output (see link): [Click for screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/246rmts/8)

The output shows that I need the call the following URL to update a user's profile: `PUT v1/users/{users}/profile/{profile}`. But I actually don't need the {profile} variable, because the `user_profiles` table doesn't have a own primary key, but only uses a foreign key called `user_id` which points to the `users` table. 

Is there any way to remove that {profile} parameter from the route without having to create a custom route for it?

Comment: No. A resource controller route will automatically create all of those for you. It's best if you create the routes manually for your profile endpoints.

Comment: thanks! I will use your approach to tackle this problem.